# Optimizing iOS method in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have such method and have a hard time optimizing it to run better. It takes roughly 1 sec with 100 units to get between `NSLog(@"Debug2")` and `NSLog(@"Debug3")`. And 2 sec on iPhone.

Method idea:

**Input**:

- `NSMutableArray` `times` - containing times (2012-12-12, 2013-01-19) and etc
- `NSMutableArray` `objectArray` - contains `LogUnit` objects.

**Output**: Array of computed views.

Main idea: a view for each time with objects from `objectArray` whose time is the same.

I have made it faster by showing a small proportion of objects (see `counted` in code and `_breakPlease`), yet it's still not fast enough.

```
- (NSMutableArray*) sortViews: (NSMutableArray *)times and:(NSMutableArray *)objectArray
{
    NSLog(@"debug2");
    NSMutableArray *views = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:times.count];

    NSString *number = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SortLog%i ",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"ObjectNumber"].intValue];

    NSString *comp = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:number];

    LogUnit *unit;

    int counted = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x != times.count; x++)
    {
        @autoreleasepool {

        UIView *foo = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400)];   
        foo.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        int f = 0;
        int h = 0;

        NSString *attributeName = @"realTime";
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K IN %@", attributeName, [times objectAtIndex:x]];
        // Filter the objectArray by the time, so we don't have to run through all the objects in objectArray, and check if time is right.
        NSArray *filtered  = [objectArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

        for(int i = 0; i != filtered.count; i++)
        {
                unit = [filtered objectAtIndex:i];

                // Filter units by user choice (comp). Like comp = Warnings or comp = Errors and etc.
                if([[unit status] isEqualToString:comp] || [comp isEqualToString:NULL] || comp == NULL)
                {
                     // testing if the unit is correct to use
                    if([unit getEvent] != NULL)
                    {
                    // below is some computation for frames, to get them to proper position
                        unit.view.frame = CGRectMake(unit.view.frame.origin.x, f * unit.view.frame.size.height + 30, unit.view.frame.size.width, unit.view.frame.size.height);
                        [foo addSubview:unit.view];
                        counted++;
                        f++;
                        h = unit.view.frame.size.height * f;
                    }
                }
        }

        UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30)];
        myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        myLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
        myLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:88 green:154 blue:251 alpha:1];
        myLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        myLabel.text = [times objectAtIndex:x];
        // Just adding a label with "2012-12-30" or etc on top of the view.    
        [foo addSubview:myLabel];

        foo.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 320, h + 30 );
        h = 0;
        [views addObject:foo];

        // counting added views for performance, if more than 30, return, and show only small portion of whole units, user has the option to show all the units if he wants to, but that takes a time to load..
        if(counted > 30 && filtered.count != counted)
        {
            if(_breakPlease == false)
            {
                _broken = true;
                break;
            }
        }
       }
    }
    NSLog(@"debug3");
    return views;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`times.count` in `for(int x = 0; x != times.count; x++)` is a method call, move it to a variable. Also, you should probably use the `<` instead of `!=` as it is more common.

However, as you don't really need the index of the element, you can replace both iterations

```
for(int i = 0; i != filtered.count; i++) {
    unit = [filtered objectAtIndex:i];
```

by native iteration

```
for (LogUnit* unit in filtered) {
```

Is `@autoreleasepool` necessary in every iteration? Having it outside `for` should help performance as well. In most application you are not required to use `@autoreleasepool` at all.

```
NSString *attributeName = @"realTime";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K IN %@", attributeName, [times objectAtIndex:x]];
// Filter the objectArray by the time, so we don't have to run through all the objects in objectArray, and check if time is right.
NSArray *filtered  = [objectArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Your filtering doesn't do what your comment describes. You don't want to run through all the objects but that's exactly the thing `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` does. Only using reflexion and moving the objects into a new array. By using the filtering code, you are losing performance.

There are various code quality issues not related to performance:

1. usage of variable names `x`, `f`, `h`, `objectArray`. Use more descriptive names or use `i`, `j`, `k` for iterators.
2. Move some code to separate methods, e.g. view generation.
3. Don't use `NULL` in Obj-C, use `nil`. `NULL` is to be used only when you interact with C pointers, not Obj-C objects.
4. `[comp isEqualToString:NULL]` will never evaluate to `YES` (`true`)
5. `if(_breakPlease == false)` Don't use `false` in Obj-C. Use `YES` or `NO`. Never ever compare a `BOOL` with a bool literal. Use logical operators instead, e.g. `if (!_breakPlease)`.

**Algorithm performance:**

The main problem of your algorithm is its complexity. Basically you have two arrays and you compare objects from an array with all objects from the other array. That's `O(n^2)`

There are many ways how you could improve this, I will list some of them:

1. Don't use a `NSArray` to store the log units. Use a `NSDictionary` where time is the key and log unit, or possibly array of log units with the same time, is the value. Finding log units with the given time will be trivial then.
2. Sort `times` and `objectArray` by time. You can then iterate through both arrays at the same time and you get `O(n + n * log n)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and tips on quality of my code. Just one thing about filteredArrayUsingPredicate.. I shouldn't use it, and just iterate through whole objectArray and inside that loop check if time is correct?

Comment: @Datenshi Yes, just remove the filtering and add a check after the second `for`.

Comment: @Datenshi Added more iteration improvements.

Answer (score 2):

if you are looping over a collection, you should use enumeration. This could be fast enumeration (as shown by Sulthan `for (LogUnit* unit in filtered)`) or even better block based enumeration.

```
[filtered enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(LogUnit *unit, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    //…
}];
```

This has <strike>two</strike> one advantage<strike>s</strike> over fast enumeration:

- <strike>it is even faster (on stack overflow some say ~15%)</strike><sub>this was misinformation</sub>
- You get also an index passed into the block, that you can use for calculating frames and similar

further benefits of enumeration in general

- The enumeration is more efficient than using NSEnumerator directly.
- The syntax is concise.
- The enumerator raises an exception if you modify the collection while  enumerating.
- You can perform multiple enumerations concurrently.

apple's doc: [Enumeration: Traversing a Collection’s Elements](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Enumerators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000135-BBCFABCB)

Comment: Do you have a link handy for the ~15% performance estimate?

Comment: Hey @Nate, see my edited answer. it is not true. and that answer disappeared from stackoverflow. indeed fast enumeration usually is a bit after than block-based enumeration.